# Android Passing String from fragment to fragment

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-fragments

I have two fragments ListNav and SwipeNav in Navigation Drawer. ListNav shows list view of data from String array. SwipeNav shows data as swipe views of the same data from string array.

I am using single fragment for viewpager swipe views multiple tabs.

My problem is :

```
When I click on B in List View, it shows A in SwipeNav,
When I click on C in List View, it shows A in SwipeNav,
When I click on D in List View, it shows A in SwipeNav,
When I click on E in List View, it shows A in SwipeNav,
```

I want to get result:

```
If I click on B in List View, it will show B in SwipeNav,
If I click on C in List View, it will show C in SwipeNav,
If I click on D in List View, it will show D in SwipeNav
```

String Array:

```
<string-array name="tab_titles">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
    <item>D</item>
    <item>E</item>
    <item>F</item>
    <item>G</item>
    <item>H</item>
    <item>I</item>
    ........
</string-array>
```

I ListNav I use below to replace to SwipeNav with OnItemClickListener:

ListNav:

```
public class ListNav extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file 
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_lis_layout, container, false);

    }

 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment12, new ListNavAdapter());
        ft.commit();
```

ListNavAdapter:

```
public class ListNavAdapter extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_list_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.tab_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String[] tabTitlesArray = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titles);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("tab_titles", tabTitlesArray[i].toString());

            SwipeNav fragobj = new SwipeNav();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), fragobj);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

In SwipeNav:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getArguments() != null && !getArguments().isEmpty()) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String myInt = bundle.getString("tab_titles");
    }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_swipe, container, false);

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

}
```

This is MyPagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private Context context;


private String[] tabTitlesArray = null;
public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);

    tabTitlesArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titles);
    this.context= context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new AFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT, tabTitlesArray[i]);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabTitlesArray.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {


    return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
}
}
```

Single fragment for tabbed activity AFragment:

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

public AFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
    // properly.


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(args.getString(ARG_OBJECT));
    return rootView;


}
```

nav_lis_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment12"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

nav_list_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I searched all answers in Stackoverflow. But fail to solve my problem why particular item click not showing same item to the next fragment.
I need your help plz.

Comment: As far as I understand - you have `ViewPager` with two (2) fragments. And you have to pass data between fragments? Click on `first fragment` show `second fragment` with proper data?

Comment: Can you upload the code somewhere? There's a lot of code and hard to understand without the full class.

Comment: @Boken I added Single fragment AFragment. I used single fragment for multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SwipeNav, after you setup the ViewPager, you have not use **viewPager.setCurrentItem()** to change to your desired page. Since **setCurrentItem()** needs an integer argument, so the clicked position in the list needs to pass from ListNavAdapter to SwipeNav.

ListNavAdapter.java:

```
public class ListNavAdapter extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_list_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.tab_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + (i +1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String[] tabTitlesArray = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titles);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("tab_titles", tabTitlesArray[i].toString());

            bundle.putInt("tab_int", i);    //Added

            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            SwipeNav fragobj = new SwipeNav();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), fragobj);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();

            //Fragment f=getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment12);
           // if(f==null){
               // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), new SwipeNav()).commit();
           // }

        }
    });
}





  // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + (position +1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Create new fragment and transaction



}
```

SwipeNav.java:

```
public class SwipeNav extends Fragment {

private MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private int tab_int;    //Added


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file 
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    //String passingString = getArguments().getString("TAG");
    if (getArguments() != null && !getArguments().isEmpty()) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String myInt = bundle.getString("tab_titles");

        tab_int = bundle.getInt("tab_int"); //Added

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_swipe, container, false);
    } else {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_swipe, container, false);
    }
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    //viewPager.setId( R.id.pager );
    viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab_int);  //Added

    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Satyanusaran Bengali");
}

}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you should not put into string commas

```
 "tabTitlesArray[i]"
```

try with

```
 ""+tabTitlesArray[i]
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion. I changed but My Problem remains same.

Comment: if you are using affragment multiple times then get your data like this: bundle.getString("object");

Comment: I tried your suggestion like: bundle.putString("object", "A");  and  bundle.getString("object");  but no solution.

Comment: I think you didnt get me. You are sending data with this key: args.putString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT, tabTitlesArray[i]); so i want you to fetch it with same key: bundle.getString("object");

Comment: I used same but no result. I am passing data from ListNavAdapter to SwipeNav. Is it the problem? I used bundle.putString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT, tabTitlesArray[i].toString()); and  String myString = bundle.getString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT);

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on B in List View, it shows A in SwipeNav,

The problem is because you are sending the same object but with different keys.

What you have to do is, in your `onClick` get the position of your adapter and put it to your `bundle`

```
bundle.putString("tab_titles", tabTitlesArray[i].toString());
```

Then you get the value using `String myString = bundle.getString("tab_titles");`

And then when you create the adapter, you can send the `String` via parameter and put the text in your adapter, anyways the code is a mess... It's very hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your Support. I edited and added all classes in the question. I added your code but same problem persists.

Comment: @achalnaskar PLEASE use the SAME KEY ALWAYS, what's this : `args.putString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT, tabTitlesArray[i]); ` listen to me please, if you want to get data, use the same key from where you send and from where you receive! I mean if you do putString(Key1,value) don't use in your get getString(key777777,value) makes no sense, ok? Check this.

Comment: Thank you Sir for Your Suggestion. I must implement your Suggestion. Till Now Problem remains same. no improvement. I click on ListNav and opens Swipenav. But passing string goes from ListNavAdapter. Is it the problem?

Comment: I recommend you to put this code into github and post in your question so I can take a look deeper

Comment: I have uploaded all to this link plz check.  https://github.com/achalnaskar/Navigation-with-swipe-views

Comment: I uploaded again the project as rar file ; Plz check : 
     https://github.com/achalnaskar/tabbed-activity-with-navigation-menu

Comment: Can you upload it as .zip please?

Comment: Sorry for late. I uploaded as .zip file. Plz check the link  https://github.com/achalnaskar/tabbed-activity

Comment: Can't make it work, please just create another repo and use the correct commands to upload it.....